# Insulation for framing around HVAC trunks with drywall

Tags: hvac, insulation, garage

There are supply and return trunks running along my (unconditioned) garage ceiling, conditioning the two floors above.

These trunks have never have any insulation or drywall around them (don't ask me, I just live here).

I would like to insulate these ducts with EPS foam board - essentially building a foam board based duct around these trunks. I would then build framing around the whole thing, and cover with 5/8" fire rated drywall.

I like the idea of foam board because it makes it relatively easy for me to "seal" these leaky ducts (panned returns, combined with not great sheet metal work. I've sealed what I can with mastic and mastic tape, but in some cases it's just not possible - at least without removing the ducts and starting over).

The idea scares me a bit though, due to the flammability of EPS. **Is rigid foam board insulation allowed in garages, if it is behind fire rated drywall? As a followup, is using it to insulate HVAC trunks a safe and sane thing to do?**